# MULTIDOMAIN - Even if I change the URL on a product, the old version is being used

Tags: product, url, magento-2.2.1, product-urls, multidomain

I am running a multidomain store, Magento 2.2.1 CE. The default value is in Danish. I created an Italian domain, where I need Italian URLs. In the backend, I go to a product, I select *Italy* as store view, and I untick every value that I don't want to be Danish. In doing that, I substitute the URL with the Italian one, but when I open the product on the website, the website is **xyz.it** but all the rest after the slash is the Danish URL. So the result is something like **xyz.it/danish-url-and-I-cant-fix-that.html**
How do I get the front end to use the URL that I specified on the backend?This happens only for some products, not for the whole store.